# Laptop screen goes black after changing the battery

Tags: laptop, display, black-screen-of-death

I have recently replaced the battery of my Asus laptop, but ever since I'm running in some problem.

I can always boot up normally and everything works fine.

When I don't have it plugged in, quite often the screen suddenly turns black (connecting to an external monitor shows everything is ok), but the laptop monitor stays black until I put it quickly into standby and back on.

When the computer is plugged in this happens as well, but only very rarely. Running on battery seems to make it much more susceptible to it.

Any suggestions why a change in battery can cause something like that?

Comment: Did you get a third-party battery, or direct from manufacturer?

Comment: Third party from amazon

Comment: Do the specs match EXACTLY what your laptop requires?

Comment: Yes, the specs match exactly. And the battery fits exactly.